# How to link releases to Jira with YAML pipelines in devops?

Tags: azure-devops, jira

[image]
The classical release pipelines had the option to report the deployment status to Jira. So when an Item was released to "acceptance" there was an option to display this in Jira.

How can this be achieved with stages in YAML pipelines? How can I report the status to Jira?

[image]